# How to create an Automation Studio exclusion AMPScript to filter the users of the last hour?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio

I would like to send an email to the users of my Exact Target list after a certain amount of time. In order to do this, I set up a workflow in Automation Studio with a **Send Email** task. Inside the configuration of this task, I select the Recipients to be my list and as an Exclusion Script, I created the following code:

```
%%[
    var @CreatedDate
    set @CreatedDate = AttributeValue("CreatedDate")

    DateDiff(@now,@CreatedDate, 'M') < 4 //I would like to exclude the emails who join the list in the last four minutes
]%%
```

Nevertheless, it is not working. Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using an Enterprise 2.0 account?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I don't know. The UX doesn't feel pretty up to date.

Comment: Do you have any other business units?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Yes, I have different "contexts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do it this way, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
%%[
    var @CreatedDate
    set @CreatedDate = AttributeValue("CreatedDate")

    if DateDiff(now(), @CreatedDate, 'MI') < 4 then
       raiseError("subscriber created in the last 4 minutes, skipped", 1)
    endif
]%%
```

Using [**raiseError()**](https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror/) will still count against your send count, even though the email is never sent.

An Exclusion Script in your Send Definition (UI or Triggered) would be a better option:

```
DateDiff(now(), AttributeValue("CreatedDate"), 'MI') < 4
```

**Reference**

- [**Now()**](https://ampscript.guide/now/)
- [**RaiseError()**](https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror/)
- [**DateDiff()**](https://ampscript.guide/datediff/)
- [**Exclusion Script**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/)